# Angular.js: custom directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-directive

I am trying to add custom directive in my app. But it is not getting called on button click event.

my controller-

```
appServices.directive('customClick', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
            $scope.deleteFieldMap = function() {
              alert('inside click');
            }
          }
  }
}
```

my jsp-

```
<button custom-click class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
                     data-style="zoom-in"
                     ng-click="deleteFieldMap(editProductJob,$index)" 
                     name="jobFileKey"
                     title="Delete" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</button>
```

What i am doing wrong here?

Comment: `restrict: 'E'` is used for element directives. What you are using is an attribute. So it should be `restrict: 'A' `

Answer (score 2):

Your directive is restricted to 'E'. Which means to "element".

You should change it to 'A' since you expect an it as an "attribute".

Check out the reference documentation :

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Edit : As explained by Medet, you also miss the "ng-model" on your element. Remove the definition if is his unecessary or add the attribute if you really expect it.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

First issue as noted above is `element.restrict: 'A'`, seconds issue - you must have `ng-model` attribute on your button, demo below

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.test = '123qe';
  }).directive('customClick', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function($scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        $scope.deleteFieldMap = function() {
          alert('inside click' + ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <button custom-click ng-click="deleteFieldMap(editProductJob,$index)" ng-model="test">
    remove
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I have another issue here.. for the first time when am loading the view $scope, element, attrs values are comming properly. on save button i am redirecting to another view, again when i am returning to current view and when deleting a row am actually getting $scope, element, attrs values as undefined.. Why so?

Comment: @JOGO not sure what causes problem, maybe open new question?

Answer (score 0):

you should use your custom directive as follow:

```
<custom-click class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
              data-style="zoom-in"
              ng-click="deleteFieldMap(editProductJob,$index)"
              name="jobFileKey"
              title="Delete" >
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
</custom-click>
```

as an element!